# web scraping error while using Beautiful soup and requests in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parser

I'm trying to write the code for tracking the amazon price of a product.The code is below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.amazon.com/LunaJany-Womens-Striped-Office-Career/dp/B01DPLT4AC/ref=sxin_7_ac_d_rm?ac_md=2-2-ZHJlc3NlcyBmb3Igd29tZW4gd29yayBjYXN1YWw%3D-ac_d_rm&crid=1POYCFAFYAR8B&cv_ct_cx=dresses+for+women+casual+summer&dchild=1&keywords=dresses+for+women+casual+summer&pd_rd_i=B01DPLT4AC&pd_rd_r=0b613dda-1077-46d2-b403-af7e15840645&pd_rd_w=7Mp2P&pd_rd_wg=rNofK&pf_rd_p=a0516f22-66df-4efd-8b9a-279a864d1512&pf_rd_r=1P30PXW75XA27N3M6VDK&psc=1&qid=1592310609&sprefix=dre%2Caps%2C440&sr=1-3-12d4272d-8adb-4121-8624-135149aa9081'
        header={"user-agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}
        page=requests.get(url,headers=header)
        soup1=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(),"html.parser")
        title=soup2.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
        print(title)
```

While trying to print the title I'm getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Patterns/PycharmProjects/RUBI/Tracks amozon prices.py", line 8, in <module>
    title=soup2.find(id="productTitle").getText()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Could anyone help me out??

Comment: The error shows getText but your code says get_text(), Which one are you using?

Comment: The posted code has `.get_text()`, but the error message says you're actually using `.getText()`.  Please post your real code.

Comment: I'm sorry that previously i have used getText and i got the above error and suddenly i thought to try get_text() but forget to replace the error here.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Patterns/PycharmProjects/RUBI/Tracks amozon prices.py", line 8, in <module>
    title=soup2.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: lots of content is generated via JavaScript, capability that BeautifulSoup don't have. but you can get luck by scrapping the json objects on the source code, but just not from the HTML directly.

Answer (score 1):

It says `NoneType` has no attribute `"get_text"`, implying that no matching element with the id `"productTitle"` was found, hence returning `None`. `None` is a `NoneType` object has therefore has no `"get_text"` attribute.

Tip - Try tweaking `productTitle`. I am not sure, but it might not be the element for price of the item you are trying to track the price of.

Answer (score 1):

Its because there is no such element like **productTitle**. When you use beautifull soup to load the page content there is a robot check page that loads instead.
Like this one.
[Robot Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3LJu.png)

Just try to print page content by - `print(soup2)` you will get to know the reason of error.